# Oracle APEX. New installation. Unable to create Work Space: PROVISION_COMPANY

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Newly installed Oracle Database 12c. While creating first Workspace in Application Express (APEX) 5.1 I've got an error: `"Error provisioning XXXXXXXXXXXX. ORA-20001: Request 1824748984765804 could not be processed. PROVISION_COMPANY"` What could "PROVISION_COMPANY" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"PROVISION_COMPANY" looks like a workspace name.

Which database version do you use? If it is 12c, have a look at ["cannot create workspace"](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3516005) OTN forums discussion. Apparently, it is about the fact that you can't create a workspace in CDB.

@BB23 said:

> I switched over to my PDB and all is good now. Interesting how EPG was happy to listen on CDB.  Beware if you're new to 12c like I am.

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL[CDB]> exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport(0);  
SQL[CDB]> alter session set container=PDBx;    
SQL[PDBx]> exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport(<port>);    
SQL[PDBx]> alter system register;    
SQL[PDBx]> @apxchpwd (again)
```

> And away we go.

Comment: By the way, "PROVISION_COMPANY" is an error code, not a workspace name. I had the same error code come up when I tried to create a workspace. (I'm yet to find out if the cause described here applies to my situation.)

Comment: Error code? Certainly doesn't look like that to me. Oh well ... I'd probably knew better if I hit it, @Jeffrey. Thank you for the info.

Comment: Actually, I'm thinking perhaps it's the name of the procedure that raised the exception.